# Not able get data into UI but got Console

Tags: angular

[This is the output i got in the console but i can't able to display it in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnvvW.png)

The thing i want to dispaly the address of customers.But the api is written like mapping address table data into customer table. So,the Output i got is like an address list in a Customer table

So,if am trying to display address from customer table,the **bindings** are not working i think so.

Can anyone resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

The angular files used are as follow.
address.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AddressService {

  selectedAddress : Address

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getCustomerAddress(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:49422/api/customer/4/profile');
  }

}
```

address.component.html

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" style="width: auto" (click)="OnCustomerAddressClick()">
            GetCustomerAddress
        </button><br>


        <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
            <tr *ngFor="let address of addressList">
              <td>
                {{address.Firstname}} - {{address.Lastname}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{address.Address1}},{{address.Address2}}
              </td>
              <td>
                  {{address.City}},{{address.Postcode}}
                </td>
            </tr>               
          </table>              
    </div>
  </div>
```

address.component.ts

```
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {

  singleAddress: Address
  addressList: Address[];
  errorMessage: string ="";

  constructor(private addressService: AddressService, private http :HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  OnCustomerAddressClick(){
    this.addressService.getCustomerAddress()
    .subscribe(
      (response:Response) => {
        this.addressList = response.json();
        console.log(this.addressList);
      },
      (error) => {
        this.errorMessage = "Unable to get Customer Address";
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: This is because you are getting object in the response and you cannot iterate on object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `response` is an object. And you are assigning `response` to `this.addressList`. So `this.addressList` contains an object not an array.

But you want to iterate on **Addresses**.

So see here, I am assigning `Address` to `this.addressList`.

```
this.addressList = response.json().Address;
```

Change function `OnCustomerAddressClick()` in **address.component.ts** as shown below.

```
  OnCustomerAddressClick(){
    this.addressService.getCustomerAddress()
    .subscribe(
      (response:Response) => {
        this.addressList = response.json().Address;
        console.log(this.addressList);
      },
      (error) => {
        this.errorMessage = "Unable to get Customer Address";
      });
  }
```

Comment: Please do up if it is helpful. And mark it right. :)